# Why doesn't Bash completion for 'cc' and 'c++' work?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

While trying to compile using a C/C++ file using `cc`/`c++` commands, I find that it is no longer possible for me to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for bash-completion.

I could do the same before 12.10. Also, when compiling with `gcc` and `g++`, bash-completion works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [bug in bash-completion](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=314417&group_id=100114&atid=413095).

Luckly there's a workaround: you can open `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cc`, find the following:

```
complete -F _gcc gcc g++ g77 gcj gpc &&
{
    cc  --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q GCC && complete -F _gcc cc  || :
    c++ --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q GCC && complete -F _gcc c++ || :
}
```

and replace it with the following:

```
complete -F _gcc gcc g++ g77 gcj gpc cc c++
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a really simple and easy way to do it :

open .bashrc file

```
$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following lines :

```
complete -f cc
complete -f c++
```